# Set state from query params

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to set state of my React component from query values.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    this.setState(query)
  }
```

It works well, but some fileds of state should be integer type. But `queryString.parse` returns objects which contains only string values. Is there any simple way to convert it? There is `Trafaret` library in Python, does JS have smth like that?

P.S. I want to use it for paginate, for example. Query params should contains offset, limit, number page etc.

Comment: `parseInt()` is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Yes I know about it of course. But I asked about some schema to parse. Like in Python's trafaret.

Comment: What about `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: @Neil, no it does not work :(

Comment: what does `this.props.location.search` look like?

Comment: end_poin/?name=test&offset=12

Comment: I think all query string params are treated as string. Always. So you need to manually convert it to required type (in your canse - Number). Regarding to some library: you can try `joi` library, it primarily used for validation purposes. It allows you to define schema (shape) of your object, specifying type for each field, like this: `birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the library `query-string`: https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string